# Eloquent Relationship on Partial Match

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Can I have an eloquent relationship where there will only be a partial match on the joins?

To explain, here is one Model;

```
class PostcodeCoord extends Model {
  public function payment()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Payment', 'Vendor ZIP', 'postcode');
  }
}
```

And my other model;

```
class Payment extends Model {
  public function postcodeCoord()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\PostcodeCoord', 'postcode', 'postcode');
  }
}
```

My `payments` table has a column called `Vendor ZIP`. And my `postcode_coords` table has a column called `postcode`.

The problem, is that the `postcode` column is only 3 or 4 characers long (the first section of a UK postcode Eg SW1A). Whereas, `Vendor ZIP`, is the full 6 or 7 characters. Eg SW1A2AA.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no way to create a relationship on a partial match between the ID fields. That said, I can think of two different ways to solve this:

1. Add a new column to your `payments` table called something like `postalcodegroup`. When the model is created or updated, ensure that this column is filled in with the first part of the postal code. The best way to do this would be via [model events](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#model-events). Then you can create your relationship between `payments.postcodegroup` and `postcode_coords.postcode`.
2. Write an [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) on the Payment model which will perform a database query to retrieve the relevant data from the `postcode_coords` table when it's called.

Of the two, option 1 is probably better (cleaner), although it does require adding columns to your tables.