# Eloquent relationship where values are formatted differently

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

We've recently switched to a new permissions system on a project I am working on.

I have completed integration for this, eloquent relationships and all, when the requirements of the integration changed a little.

The permission system integrates with all of our systems across our infrastructure, and when it comes to referencing users from the Laravel project, the value in the permissions system is slightly different; in that it is prefixed with `user-`.

For example, a user with the username `james` in my `users` table is referenced as `user-james` in the permissions system table.

Is there any way to specify the value the eloquent relationship should look at?

I could just add a column to the users table to store the primary key of this user as it exists in the permissions table, but I wanted to see if there was a way to do this with eloquent.

Comment: why dont you create simply are raltionship between user and permission table. In your user class write a method as permission() and put relation as `$this->hasOne('App\Permission', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`. whats the problem with this???  but here put foreign_key as other table's column name and the local_key as username

Comment: @webDev `foreign_key` and `local_key` are where you specify the column that the relationship should reference. They don't allow you to specify the format of the value, unless there is something I am missing?

Comment: Yes but those are column name not values stored in that colume (whatver format is). Or simply I did not get your question. Oh yeah i got you now, hehehe my bad. let me see in your case

Comment: @webDev perhaps I can clarify. The `username` of the user in my `users` table is `james`. The username of the `user` in the permissions table is `user-james`. Whilst I can specify the specific columns that the eloquent relationship should use, I don't think you can use it to specify the format of the value.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29922813/eloquent-relationship-on-partial-match

Comment: I could, but then I at modifying a system that could change in the future. I will probably end up adding a column to the users table to store the key for the user in the permissions table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we consider relation is one - one we can do something like below:

First extend `BelongsTo` relation and change condition on where clause:

```
class CustomBelongsTo extends BelongsTo
{
    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    public function addConstraints()
    {
        if (static::$constraints) {
            // For belongs to relationships, which are essentially the inverse of has one
            // or has many relationships, we need to actually query on the primary key
            // of the related models matching on the foreign key that's on a parent.
            $table = $this->related->getTable();

            $this->query->where($table.'.'.$this->otherKey, '=', 'user-'.$this->parent->{$this->foreignKey});
        }
    }

}
```

Then override `belongsTo` method on your model to use this custom relation.

```
class User extends Model {

    protected $table = 'users';

    public function permissions(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Permission:class, 'username');
    }

    public function belongsTo($related, $foreignKey = null, $otherKey = null, $relation = null)
    {
        // If no relation name was given, we will use this debug backtrace to extract
        // the calling method's name and use that as the relationship name as most
        // of the time this will be what we desire to use for the relationships.
        if (is_null($relation)) {
            list($current, $caller) = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 2);

            $relation = $caller['function'];
        }

        // If no foreign key was supplied, we can use a backtrace to guess the proper
        // foreign key name by using the name of the relationship function, which
        // when combined with an "_id" should conventionally match the columns.
        if (is_null($foreignKey)) {
            $foreignKey = Str::snake($relation).'_id';
        }

        $instance = new $related;

        // Once we have the foreign key names, we'll just create a new Eloquent query
        // for the related models and returns the relationship instance which will
        // actually be responsible for retrieving and hydrating every relations.
        $query = $instance->newQuery();

        $otherKey = $otherKey ?: $instance->getKeyName();

        return new CustomBelongsTo($query, $this, $foreignKey, $otherKey, $relation);
    }
}
```

I hope this help.

Comment: This looks promising. I am using a `hasOne` relationship, but I assume I can do the same as the above by looking at how the original class is built.
For the custom class, do I just extend it inside the file of the original?

Comment: If you want to reuse it anywhere else extract it as `CustomModel` and extends it in other models otherwise there is no point to extract it as new class.

Comment: I want to do the above, but with a `hasOne` relationship. Which file do I create the custom class in? Are you able to give an example, like the above, of how I can do this with a `hasOne` relationship?